Is there any prettier rule for 'inserting spaces after opening and before closing parenthesis'?
I can achieve this in vscode by using:
{
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": true,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets": true,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyParenthesis": true,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces": true,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingEmptyBraces": false
}

But then I moved to Neovim and I can't have these anymore, I have been using conform which allows me to set up custom prettier config. But i can't seem to find it.
PS. I have tried eslint but it only has the rule, which will throw an error whether there is spacing or not. And i'm looking for formatting not linting.
Edit 1: SOLVED:
answer was, how about you RTFM to myself and then create an autocmd. docs where always here
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePre", {
    desc = 'Format on save - TYPESCRIPT ONLY',
    pattern = { "*.ts", "*.tsx" },
    callback = function(args)
        vim.lsp.buf.format({
            bufnr = args.buf,
            formatting_options = {
                insertFinalNewline = true,
                trimTrailingWhitespace = true,

                insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces = true,
                insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets = true,
                insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyParenthesis = true,
                insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces = true,
                insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingEmptyBraces = false
            }
        })
    end,
})


If you solve your own question, don't edit/retag it - put it in a self answer so people can see it more easily!
